# javascript global multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables

I am working on JavaScript for the first time in my life, and something basic is not really working so I am trying to understand where I am going wrong.

I have a multidimensional array, as a global variable

```
var unit_count = [[],[],[],[],[],[]];
```

and then I have something like this inside a class method.

```
if (!unit_count[3].includes(this.me.id)){

        unit_count[3].push(this.me.id);

        this.log("Added: " + this.me.id + "|length: " + unit_count[3].length);

    }
```

What happens is that each time a the method is run, a new `this.me.id` pushed to `unit_count[3][0]`, but they don't stick around for the next call and the next this me id is again added to the `unit_count[3][0]` and the previous value is now lost.

At first I thought I was having a problem with the global variable concepts in javascript but I have other global variables work as expected between method calls.

**is there any language/syntax related reasons this isn't working?** I confused myself a little bit with other answers I found online which some of them said "Javascript doesn't have multidimensional arrays", So I am trying to make sure I am not making some language/syntax related mistake.

Comment: Please post a full [MCVE] that illustrates the problem

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, I tried to just that. Any specific suggestion on what I should've included or discarded?

Comment: Take the full code that reproduces the problem, then remove as much of it as you can such that the problem is still evident, then edit the result into a live snippet in the question. See [MCVE]. There is not enough code in the question to know what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure that your "global variable" is really global and persistent across calls?

Comment: I am.  I have both a const value and a var that is correctly incremented across multiple calls. I am definitely doing something weird, because even if it is a simple array, whenever I add a new value, the entire contents of that array become the same, most recently added value.

Comment: @C.O. I've added a code snippet but you won't see it until its peer reviewed. If you want help with this you're going to have make the tests at the bottom of the snippet fail.